# What kind of ivy plants are these?

Tags: identification, vines, creepers, poison-ivy

My family and I recently moved into a new home, I noticed these ivies everywhere in our backyard and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what they are.

I know little of ivies/vines and I am a little concerned that these ivies could be poison ivy. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image: leaves]

[image: closeup of buds]

Album of more photos:
http://s82.photobucket.com/albums/j257/lacee_06/

please note that the ivy I labeled "type 2" is covering an oleander shrub so you may see oleander leaves in the photo. Once again thank you for your time!

Comment: It's not poison ivy and it doesn't look like the ivy I know Hedera helix.

Comment: Those flowers resemble [Greenbrier (*Smilax*) flowers](http://www.alabamaplants.com/Whitealt/Smilax_auriculata_page.html). Do they have six folded back petals? Five petals would indicate *Hedera* (English Ivy and the like). Look for occasional thorns on the older, woodier stems. There are many different kinds of greenbrier each with highly variable foliage. It is hard to know which one it could be. Where do you live?

Comment: what part of the world do you live in?

Comment: I live in South Texas. No, I didn't notice any thorns at all on the older stems. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: I also wanted to note that I added a link to the bottom of the post that has more photos...perhaps they could give you more of an idea.

Comment: The second photo looks like *Parthenocissus tricuspidata*, but I don't live in that region, so... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocissus_tricuspidata

Answer (score 2):

They look to me like a member of the Cissus Genus, Vitacea (Grape) Family, probably something along the lines of Cissus trifoliata. [This](http://www.flickr.com/photos/39039456@N07/8055663181/) and [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/39039456@N07/8055663181/) flickr images look very similar to me. The Dave's Garden page [here](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/61655/) also has more info and pictures that look about right.

FWIW, ivies have more of a point on the tip of their foils but yours look to almost be round.

Answer (score 0):

What makes the vine an ivy? Isn't the plant **Akebia Quinata Chocolate Vine Plant**?

[image: Akebia quinata Chocolate Vine Plant]?

"An evergreen perennial twining vine native to Japan, China and Korea. This Five Leaf Akebia can grow to 30' with strong vines bursting with clusters of five oblong leaves."